# Log monitoring with pythonic tail -f and process killing

Tags: python, beginner, status-monitoring

The purpose of this cluster of functions is to tail the log file and kill/restart processes from shell (the latter is not yet implemented).

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os
import re


def read_log(f):
    """
    Basically tail -f
    """
    logfile = open(f)
    logfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    while True:
        new_line = logfile.readline()
        if new_line:
            yield new_line
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)


def find_error(line, base_time, line_time):
    """
    Search for ERROR keyword in log line. Return True if found, False if not.
    """
    match = re.search('.*ERROR.*', line)
    if match and line_time < base_time:
        return True
    return False


def parse_time(line):
    """
    Parse string to datetime
    """
    date_regex = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'
    date_string = re.search(date_regex, line).group(0)
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


def increase_base_time(line_time):
    """
    Return a datetime that is line_time plus one minute
    """
    return line_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)


def monitor(filename):
    """
    Read from a log file.
    For each line check if log line time is later than base comparison time.
    If so, update the base time and set error count to 0.
    Check for errors in line. Increment error count if any are found.
    Check the total error count. If it's greater than five, restart the logged 
    process. 
    Check if process has been restarted before. If so, kill the logged process.
    """
    count = 0
    base_time = datetime.datetime.min
    log = read_log(filename)
    restarted = False
    for line in log:
        line_time = parse_time(line)
        if line_time > base_time:
            base_time = increase_base_time(line_time)
            count = 0
        if find_error(line, base_time, line_time):
            count += 1
        if count >= 5:
            if restarted:
                print("Kill the process") # A placeholder, sorry
            else: 
                print("Restart the process") # Also a placeholder, sorry
                count = 0
                restarted = True


monitor(sys.argv[1])
```

There are a lot of if-statement for doing checks. I thought about making this class based, but it really doesn't make sense to do it (functions don't need to share states and it is a rather small program). 
Is the number of if's acceptable? How could I refactor the code to make it flow a bit better?

EDIT: As this was brought up, is it necessary that the tailing function would be non blocking? As I understand I wont be doing nothing until a line is yielded. What would be the benefits of going one way or the other?

Answer (score 5):

Using regex for such a simple task as finding if a line contains a string is not worth it. The built-in `str.__contains__`, being called by the keyword `in` is faster in this case.

Here are some worst case (i.e. a string that does not contain the string `"ERROR"`) timings for the two functions:

```
import re

def using_in(s):
    return "ERROR" in s

def using_re(s):
    return bool(re.search('.*ERROR.*', s))
```

[image]

Using `re` is always slower in this case. It does, of course, have its uses for more complex patterns. Note that the `re` module also compiles the regex automatically (and caches it), so that is not a way to make it faster in this case, since it is always the same regex being used.

Let's just hope your lines are less than 10,000 characters long.

---

In general, I think you still have to find a good balance between not having enough functions and having too many. IMO, instead of having a `increase_base_time` function, I would have a global constant and inline the call:

```
INCREMENT = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

...

for line in log:
    ...
    if line_time > base_time:
        base_time = line_time + INCREMENT
        ...
```

---

If `read_log` is a `tail -f` equivalent, you could just call it `tail_f`. In any case, I would make the sleep time an optional parameter.

Note that your function does not ensure that the file is properly closed, which might cause issues. You should always use the `with` keyword to avoid this.

```
def read_log(f, sleep=0.1):
    """
    Basically tail -f with a configurable sleep
    """
    with open(f) as logfile:
        logfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        while True:
            new_line = logfile.readline()
            if new_line:
                yield new_line
            else:
                time.sleep(sleep)
```

This way the file is closed even if the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

---

You should only call your function under a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script without it (trying and failing to) run:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    monitor(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: No `with open(f) as logfile:` for file handling ?

Comment: Dunno where you live, but over here it's 5 PM on a friday. It happens *shrug*

Comment: @Gloweye It is here as well. And just before the friday beer. I blame it on that.

Comment: I wonder if calling `select.select([logfile], [], [])` would work and be better than this ugly `sleep`…

Comment: @409_Conflict I did not know `select`, but it seems like you would at least lose portability to Windows. Since I don't have a clue about it, maybe you should add an answer with this?

Comment: @Graipher Nice catch with the portability. But since it is `trail -f` I assumed Linux anyway.

Comment: Also re regex timings, wouldn't it make sense to try and time `re.search('.*?ERROR.*')` instead?

Comment: @409_Conflict It might, if the OP has more knowledge of the structure, it should of course be included in the pattern. But I just copied it directly from the OP. In any case, it is a worst case timing, i.e. the string/pattern does not appear at all. So it just times the time it takes to scan the whole string for the pattern.

Comment: @409_Conflict Just tried it, it is even slower, by about a factor 10.

Comment: Lol, guess I will never fully understand backtracking then.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I really hadn't thought about closing the file (since I assumed it will be opened all the time). I guess I went wit `re` so that the project could handle more complex searches. I think I need to rethink what am I trying to look for.

Comment: Well nevermind, select won't work as the file is always ready for reading (even though it's only EOF)... Just tried it...

Answer (score 2):

> *... about making this class based, but it really doesn't make sense to do
>   it ...*

I'd not agree with that, because:

- same arguments `filename/f` and `line` are passed around across multiple functions
- with custom class approach the *things* can be initialized/defined at once (on *class* definition or instantiation phase)
- with OOP approach I'm confident that functions like `parse_time(line)` or `find_error(line, ...)` are not passed with undesirable or "tricky" `line` argument, as the line being currently read can be encapsulated.

---

List of issues (with support of OOP approach):

- pattern `date_regex = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'`. 
  Instead of generating regex pattern on each call of `parse_time` function - we'll just make it a class **`LogMonitor`** constant called **`DATE_REGEX`**. 
  Furthermore, we can precompile the regex pattern with [`re.complie`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) function:

> using `re.compile()` and saving the resulting regular expression
>   object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used
>   several times in a single program

```
    DATE_REGEX = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

- `increase_base_time` function. 
  `datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)` is easily extracted to another constant:

  ```
  INC_MINUTE = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
  ```
- **`find_error(line, base_time, line_time)`** function.
  Besides of simplifying `ERROR` pattern search (as @Graipher mentioned) the function has another issue as it introduces an unnecessary coupling/dependency on two external identifiers `base_time` and `line_time` - whereas the sufficient function's responsibility is *"check if `ERROR` occurs within the current log line"* (returning boolean result)
  That dependency should be eliminated. 
  To "beat" that, the crucial conditional within `monitor` function that calls the `find_error` function can be restructured to present a *natural* order of mutually *exclusive* conditions:

  ```
      ...
      if line_time > base_time:
          base_time = self.increase_base_time(line_time)
          count = 0
      elif self.find_error():
          count += 1
  ```

---

In below OOP implementation the input *filename* is passed at once to `LogMonitor` constructor as `LogMonitor(sys.argv[1])`, the functions are logically renamed, the needed state/behavior is encapsulated, the above mentioned OOP benefits/arguments included.

```
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os
import re


class LogMonitor:
    DATE_REGEX = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
    INC_MINUTE = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._fname = filename
        self._log = self._read_log()    # generator
        self._curr_line = ''

    def _read_log(self):
        """Basically tail -f"""
        with open(self._fname) as logfile:
            logfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            while True:
                new_line = logfile.readline()
                if new_line:
                    self._curr_line = new_line
                    yield self._curr_line
                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)

    def _has_error(self):
        """
        Search for ERROR keyword in log line. Returns boolean result"""
        return 'ERROR' in self._curr_line

    def _parse_datetime(self):
        """Parse string to datetime"""
        date_string = self.DATE_REGEX.search(self._curr_line).group(0)
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    def increase_base_time(self, line_time):
        """Return a datetime that is line_time plus one minute"""
        return line_time + self.INC_MINUTE

    def run(self):
        """
        Read from a log file.
        For each line check if log line time is later than base comparison time.
        If so, update the base time and set error count to 0.
        Check for errors in line. Increment error count if any are found.
        Check the total error count. If it's greater than five, restart the logged
        process.
        Check if process has been restarted before. If so, kill the logged process.
        """
        count = 0
        base_time = datetime.datetime.min
        restarted = False

        for line in self._log:
            line_time = self._parse_datetime()
            if line_time > base_time:
                base_time = self.increase_base_time(line_time)
                count = 0
            elif self._has_error():
                count += 1

            if count >= 5:
                if restarted:
                    print("Kill the process")  # A placeholder, sorry
                else:
                    print("Restart the process")  # Also a placeholder, sorry
                    count = 0
                    restarted = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    monitor = LogMonitor(sys.argv[1])
    monitor.run()
```

Comment: Thank you! Those are good points and I think I am actually switching over to using a class. Just to clarify the `line_time` and `base_time` thing in `find_error`: the idea was to look for errors within a set time frame (like if there has been five or more errors within a minute). I really should have made it more clear, sorry. Also a question: could I call the `read_log` inside the `run` function instead? Because that seems to be the only one using it? Or is there a important reason why to call it in the class variables (`self._log = self._read_log()`)? Thanks!

Comment: @sjne, `self._read_log()` is just scheduling a generator. Making it on class instantiation phase is a generic way. If your implementation is expected to be simplified and never be extended - you may move it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution.

You should not make the while True loop, instead of that you should use **inotify** in order to been notify only when changes happen on the file that you are monitoring, here is a short code.

```
import inotify.adapters

def _read_log(self):
    i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()

    i.add_watch(f)

    with open(f, 'w'):
        pass

    for event in i.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
        (_, type_names, path, filename) = event

        do_work()
```

Basically your process will be only unblock until there are some changes on the file that you are monitoring.

Comment: Thank you! Just started to look into it. As far as I understand it at the moment, I'd be using `inotify` to track an event and then read the log file lines if there's a change? 
So `doWork()` would mean something like yielding or returning `logfile.readline()`? Sorry, I'm a bit lost as to how to actually get the changed line (cause `inotify` only returns a generator about the event?). Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: For example could I just replace `do_work()` with `yield logfile.readline()`? And can I add `logfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` after `with open(f, 'w') as logfile`?

Comment: I tried it as described above (plus replaced the `pass` with the `for event` block and used the `add_watch()` with the constant `IN_MODIFY`). A loop was logging two lines every 30 seconds to the log file and inotify did pick it up but often it would just skip one of the lines and print it 30 seconds later.